# Can Hibernate 2.1.7 work with Oracle Database 11gR2?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, weblogic11g, oracle11gr2

A quick and simple question: has anybody used the combination of Hibernate 2.1.7 and Oracle 11gR2 database? We have a legacy app that is using Hibernate 2.1.7 (which we are not planning to update at this point in time) and our database back-end is being upgraded to Oracle 11gR2. Is there any issues we need to be aware of?

Thanks!

Comment: from which Oracle version do you come? Can Hibernate 2.1.7 work with the latest Oracle JDBC drivers?

Comment: @ik_zelf coming from oracle 10, via Weblogic 10.3, and JDBC driver 11.1.0.6.0 - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jdbc driver 11.1.0.6.0 you can connect to Oracle 11gR2. No problem.
A simple issue that you might run into is the case of username and passwords. In 11g this is case sensitive, before that version it was not case sensitive.

An other nice one is that accounts now default expire. Check that with your local dba.

You should test the app during the upgrade tests. Database features change, optimizer features change, so the app behaviour could change. Technically I see no reasons why it would not work but knowing some software projects .... Test it. In many cases it does not give any problems at all. A lot depends on the quality of the code. If your app's code is working because it is based on a bug in Oracle that is now solved, you will run into an issue.